# Minimizing queries - Sorting results from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `client` who `has_many :tasks`.  I want to sort these tasks into separate variables, or hash, that is available to my view depending on the date that they are due.

I'm trying to minimize queries, and I know at this point I should probably pull all tasks for a client, then sort each task into a variable.  I can do this using a controller method and a `before_filter` when loading the `show` action:

```
 def build_client_tasks
    @tasks = client.tasks.due
    @tasks_today = []
    @tasks_tomorrow = []
    @tasks_upcoming = []
    @tasks_later = []
    for task in @tasks
      if task.due_date <= Date.today
        @tasks_today << task
      elsif task.due_date == Date.tomorrow
        @tasks_tomorrow << task
      elsif task.due_date > Date.tomorrow && task.due_date <= 7.days.from_now.to_date
        @tasks_upcoming << task
      else
        @tasks_later << task
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there a better/smarter way to do this?  This works fine, but what if I want to reload these tasks when a user adds a new task via AJAX?  I'm then forced to duplicate this code in my *.js.erb file so that they are available when the tasks partial is reloaded.

There must be a better way.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is there any reason you are reloading all the tasks? Why don't you simply add the new task to the appropriate area of the page without having to reload any of the existing ones?

Comment: That's a good point.  I was just reloading the tasks div, but I also have a rescheduling feature of each task and that helped ease up on the JS code quite a bit.  I can give that a shot.  So the way I was sorting the results in the controller is correct?

Comment: Looks like that will do the trick but I'll need a lot more javascript to get it to work the way I want it.  I have some headers that display and hide if there are tasks for certain time frames, so my next step is just to add more logic into the javascripts that's called on create and destroy.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment: I would not create different database cells. You should only have one with a due_date. Then you do a scope with block like this:

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

```
scope :due_dated, lambda {|date| where(:due_date => date) }
```

end

You can then do something like this:

```
Task.due_dated(Date.today)
```

Hi Steve, 
you might want to try to define it in your tasks/client model.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

named_scope :today, :conditions => { :due => Date.today }

...

end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.tasks_due_today
    tasks.today
end 

end
```

and in your view something like this:

```
<%=  @client.tasks_due_today. each do |ct| %>
<li><%=  ct.content  %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thanks - that's what I did from the start but I have tasks due today, tomorrow, this week, and beyond so that created 4 separate database calls.  I wanted to narrow that down to just one, and then sort them out using ruby logic in the controller to cut down on queries.  Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to put this login into your task model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Returns upcoming tasks in a hash in the form:
  # { :today => [ task... ], :tomorrow => [ task...], :upcoming => [ task... ], :later => [ task... ] }
  def upcoming
    due.group_by do |t|
      if t.due_date <= Date.today
        :today
      elsif t.due_date == Date.tomorrow
        :tomorrow
      elsif t.due_date <= .days.from_now.to_date
        :upcoming
      else
        :later
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So that you can then do things like `client.tasks.upcoming` from anywhere. E.g. a view might look like this:

```
<% tasks = client.tasks.upcoming %>
<h2>Today's tasks</h2>
<%= render :collection => tasks[:today] %>
<h2>Tomorrow's tasks</h2>
<%= render :collection => tasks[:tomorrow] %>
<h2>Next 7 days</h2>
<%= render :collection => tasks[:upcoming] %>
<h2>Later</h2>
<%= render :collection => tasks[:later] %>
```

In Rails 3, this'll render an instance of your '_task.html.erb' partial for each task in the list.

Equally, you could call this method from your `.js.erb`, or you could return this as JSON from your controller using `.to_json` and then dynamically render it on the client side.

Comment: I was looking for something like this too!  I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to return a hash from the model the way you've shown it.  I'm still wondering though - 4 separate DB calls vs. just one.  Is the difference really that negligible?

Comment: I might be getting confused, but that _should_ only make one call - the grouping is done by iterating through the results. See Enumerable's 'group_by' operation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001497

Comment: I've ended up using a presenter with memoization to organize it al and save on the queries.  I did use the above for quite a while; I simply looped through each task and assigned it to the appropriate array in a @tasks hash and that worked well.